# Make UITableView use all available space below subview

Tags: ios, uitableview, calendar

I'm trying to create a similar calendar screen in my iOS 7 application to the built-in Calendar App, which shows a calendar month view, with a `UITableView` below it. However, what I'm after is for the `UITableView` to automatically use up all available space beneath the calendar - a month that shows with 5 weeks needs more space than a month with 4 weeks.

I'm using the [Vurig Calendar](https://github.com/tjeerdintveen/Vurig-Calendar) framework as a calendar, which is added as a `subView` to the main view. I created the `UITableView` in StoryBoard, so it's position is fixed. I'm not sure how to go about redrawing the `UITableView` to make it use the available space? Is it possible to detect the bottom of the calendar `subView` and then push the `UITableView` up to that point on the display?

Here are a couple of images to show what I mean a little clearer: [image: the screen showing the largest gap.] [image: the screen showing the smallest gap]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the following changes in VRGCalendarViewDelegate method

```
-(void)calendarView:(VRGCalendarView *)calendarView switchedToMonth:(int)month targetHeight:(float)targetHeight animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration = animated ? 0.3 :0.0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{
        CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
        frame.origin.y = CGRectGetMinX(calendarView.frame) + targetHeight;
        frame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height - frame.origin.y;
        self.tableView.frame = frame;
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code i believe you have some properties such as calendarView and tableView

In your viewDidLoad you could add

```
CGRect calendarFrame = calendarView.frame;
CGRect tableViewFrame = tableView.frame;
tableViewFrame.origin.y = calendarFrame.origin.y+calendarFrame.size.height;
tableView.frame = tableViewFrame;
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much! Although I had to fix a small error with your solution, it needs to be `tableViewFrame.origin.y` and `calendarFrame.origin.y`, rather than `.x` to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your view hierarchy is like that:

```
-view
  -calendar
  -tableview
```

then try auto layout in your storyboad between calendar and tableview. Here's [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2)!